# Force Doctrine Migrations to generate "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [name]..." instead of "CREATE TABLE [name]..." in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, migration

By default, if new entity is introduced to mapped code-base, Doctrine Migrations will produce SQL statement looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE offloading_result (id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

but because I have to deal with covering with entities both new application and legacy database I need to run migrations on both new & existing DB. Existing DB does not have migrations versions table and I want to fill it by running the migrations, but with CREATE it would result in error, so my solution is to manually edit all migrations and replace above with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS offloading_result (id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Is it possible to define on Entity/Migrations config to be default behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be necessary to modify the config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml file and define the default option with "IF NOT EXISTS"

```
doctrine_migrations:
    storage:
        table_name: migration_versions
    all_or_nothing: true
    check_database_platform: true
    custom_template: ~
    create_params:
        options: "IF NOT EXISTS"
```

If it doesn't work you can make a change to the migration code directly

```
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE offloading_result (id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))';

    if ($this->connection->getSchemaManager()->tablesExist(['offloading_result'])) {
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS offloading_result (id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))';
    }

    $this->addSql($sql);
}
```

With this approach, you can write custom migrations to handle application-specific behaviors